# Not getting survey info in an SurveyMonkey API call

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm trying to get the entered information on a survey of SurveyMonkey through the API. But i'm getting the following return message: "Could not validate access to survey at this time, please try again later.", with status 5 (System Error).

I'm working with a APP in Draft status. All the scopes in my app are put on optional. And other api calls (like get_survey_list) do give me data.

I'm working with php, but the API console (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/api_console/) also gives me these results.

Is there an extra permission layer i'm missing? Do ppl need to approve something through oauth?

Comment: For anybody who is interested. I've started a GIT project for a PHP Survey Monkey API v3 on Github. https://github.com/lyfter/SurveyMonkey_API_v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API console is for V2 of the API (which is either deprecated, or likely to be deprecated soon), I would recommend using V3 (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3)

You can fetch the list of surveys using

```
GET /v3/surveys
```

And you can get a specific survey with

```
GET /v3/surveys/<id>
```

And follow down the path to get individual pages/questions, or if you want the entire survey expanded at once, use:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<id>/details
```

With regards to the request you are doing with API v2, I'd probably need a bit more information, if you are doing a POST with an empty body to get_survey_list and are getting that issue I'd probably contact their customer support to look into it as it looks like a server error. But I would recommend going to V3 and see if everything works fine for you.

Comment: Thanks, v3 works allright :) unfortunately there is no PHP lib for it. So i'll post some code i used for other developers to use.

Answer (score 1):

Like the general posted, v3 works fine. Here is the code of my POC that works:

```
// GET USER
$requestHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]',
);

$url = 'https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/users/me?api_key=[API_KEY]';

$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The above is the just a simple call to get the basic info of the user.

The next call get's the answers given in the responses that are given through a specific collector.

```
// GET THE ANSWERS OF THE SURVEY
$requestHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]',
);

$url = 'https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors/[COLLECTOR_ID]/responses/bulk?api_key=[API_KEY]';

$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You can also import the API into Postman. There is a button for this on the documentation site. Pretty nice :)